# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Importing g which does not have a ɵmod property

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

We have ionic 6 project with capacitor .

Currently we are on capacitor 2 so our native apps are build using capacitor 2 version.

When I update capacitor version to 4 we got below errors in native apps.Both android and Ios.

And thais error also not came every time.This will only generates when I use redirection functionality for first time(Suppose I am on login page and try to redirect to password page).

On web it works perfectly with Ionic serve.

I am also not clear error message is what about?
Importing g means which package?

[image]

Comment: Hard to make any suggestions if you don't post code. The error is pretty vague!

Comment: @MarsAndBack
My project is very big and I also don't know from which part this error was produced.

This will happen when I redirect to some page first time.Suppose on first page I have button and on click of that I redirect my app to page2.So on first click it didn't redirect to that page it providing this error.Once I retry same and if that works then my whole app routing worked fine.